# Graph API: Post Image to User's wall (without Album)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, photo

I am somewhat desperate posting images via the graph api to a user's page.

What I want to achieve is: I've got an image in an amazon S3 bucket. I'm using the /userid/photos endpoint to post the image url and the message property  like:

```
{
"url": "http://url.to/image.jpg",
"message": "Image description"
}
```

Now, the API creates an album called: "AppName Photos". When I post multiple time to the same album, it suddenly arranges all images in a view, but I want them to be seperate posts each by each.

So, what I want to achieve is: Post an image to a user's page without putting it into an album, as if the user uploaded the image hisself.

www.klout.com is able to do this. When I try to share & upload a custom image, the image is being stored in the "Chronic photos". How can I store the image there and not in an app-dependent album?

Answer (score 0):

Got it. Simply iterate over all albums (you need user_photo access) and post to that specific album of type "wall".
It is not the most beautiful solution I've ever seen but at least it works and prevents grouping nicely :)

Comment: How do you iterate over all albums?

Comment: when I use wall, it gives me an exception (OAuthException - #2500) Unknown path components: /wall